# Internet connection slow only on http downloads (but not on speedtest)

Tags: router, internet, download, http, isp

Here are the facts:

- I have 1gbps broadband connection with my ISP in Catalonia
- I download very fast using Torrent, Steam, Epic Games launcher, etc. at like over 100mb/s
- SpeedTest also shows arround 950ish mbps, which is close to 1gbps

But when it comes to http downloads, it is very very slow, like 1mb/s or something. I've tried for example these links:

- https://www.thinkbroadband.com/download
- https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Here are the results:

- Friend with ISP A @ 500mbps connection downloads the files at arround **55mb/s**
- At Work with ISP B @ 100mbps connection downloads the files at arround **11mb/s**
- **At home** with **ISP C @ 1000mbps** connection downloads the files at arround **1mb/s**

I contacted my ISP and they say my connection is fine and that if they have to send a technician they will charge me.

Here are my thoughts:

- The http protocol per se is not limited I think, since if I put many parallel http downloads the total download speed is higher than 1mb/s
- This problem does not have to do with the speed of the server where I am downloading from, since the tests were made at the same time of the day with my friend and he was constantly getting the way higher speed than I did
- My home router does not have in place any kind of bandwitch limitation that I know of
- Speed is fine with the rest of stuff, youtube, netflix, steam, torrent...

Thoughts?

Comment: Is your ISP Jazztel?

Comment: No @GabrielaGarcia, it's a local ISP from Catalonia called XTA. Why?

Comment: Because the other day I've noticed the exact same problem as you described at a local with Jazztel. By the way, visca catalunya!

Comment: It is a really weird behaviour and I do not have enough networking knowdledge to grasp what is going on... Lliure! :))

Comment: You definitely know more than I do. I have no thoughts. If it were the same ISP and in the absence of other reports we could pinpoint the issue. But XTA.cat seems to have no relationship with Jazztel.

Comment: Your ISP might have bad peering and you're not getting a good connection to the server. They might also be limiting it for whatever reason. The Ubuntu download uses a CDN so your friend and you might have reached very different servers. Your/their ISP might also be doing some form of caching on their own network. Rather than having friends that all have a different ISP you'd need to have someone who uses the same ISP to see whenever the behavior is the same for him.

Comment: Hello @Seth, we made sure we reached the same server/file. I'm trying to find someone who has the same ISP to test this out. Meanwhile, is there a way to check if there is a limitation ISP side? What about cheking if the peering is bad?

Comment: You already ran a test which shows that it's likely a ISP limitation (assuming you're really reaching the same server). Another option would be to use a VPN. If you're reaching a higher speed using a VPN it's more likely that the issue is that particular connection. If it's a common issue for the users of the same ISP it's likely down to their configuration. If it is not, it's your configuration/individual connection. As you know other HTTP services that work fine, it's likely limited to a certain website/service.